# Rust-based kernel triggers a "Invalid Opcode" interrupt

Tags: rust, x86, bootloader, osdev, low-level

Said kernel is from [this repo](https://github.com/ThatCodingGuy86/MimosaOS) in `src/kernel/core/main.rs`.
The bootloader is from the same repo in `src/bootloader/bootloader.c`.

The steps the bootloader takes are:

- Do UEFI functionality checks
- Get a framebuffer from the Graphics Output Protocol
- Load the kernel from the storage media
- Get the memory map
- Call ExitBootServices
- Do various checks to make sure kernel is valid
- Jump to an address computed via `kernelAddress + prog_entry`,
  passing in framebuffer info and memory map info

The steps the kernel takes are:

- Clear the screen
- Draw a line going from 20, 1 to 20, 8
- Loop indefinitely

Here's the code that loads the kernel in the bootloader:

```
    // ...
    
    // Get a volume handle to the volume the bootloader has been loaded from

    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE *loaded_image = NULL;                  // Image interface
    EFI_GUID lipGuid = EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL_GUID;      // Image interface GUID
    EFI_FILE_IO_INTERFACE *IOVolume;                        // File system interface
    EFI_GUID fsGuid = EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL_GUID; // File system interface GUID
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE volumeHandle;                           // The volume's interface
 
    // Get the loaded image protocol interface for the "image"
    uefi_call_wrapper(BS->HandleProtocol, 3, ImageHandle, &lipGuid, (void**) &loaded_image);
    // Get the volume handle
    uefi_call_wrapper(BS->HandleProtocol, 3, loaded_image->DeviceHandle, &fsGuid, (void*)&IOVolume);
    // VolumeHandle = LibOpenRoot(loaded_image->DeviceHandle); // Not sure if this works, so this is commented out
    uefi_call_wrapper(IOVolume->OpenVolume, 2, IOVolume, &volumeHandle);


    EFI_FILE_HANDLE kernelHandle; // Kernel file handle

    // Get a handle to the kernel file
    uefi_call_wrapper(volumeHandle->Open, 5, volumeHandle, &kernelHandle, L"kernel.elf", EFI_FILE_MODE_READ, EFI_FILE_READ_ONLY | EFI_FILE_HIDDEN | EFI_FILE_SYSTEM);
    
    // Read from the kernel file and load it into memory

    //initPageDir();
    //initPage();
    //loadPageDir(pageDirectory);

    uint64_t kernelSize = FileSize(kernelHandle);

    #define PAGE_SIZE 4096
    #define PRE_ALLOC 100

    // Allocate (kernelSize / PAGE_SIZE) + PRE_ALLOC pages for the kernel. UEFI initilizes the VAS as identity mapped,
    // so I can't use AllocatePool, as the kernel address will be inconsistent otherwise.

    UINTN numPages = (kernelSize / (PAGE_SIZE)) + PRE_ALLOC;

    Print(L"Pages to allocate: %d", numPages);

    void* kernelAddress = (void*)0x10000;

    Status = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->AllocatePages, 4, AllocateAnyPages, EfiLoaderCode, numPages, (EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS*)&kernelAddress);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status) || kernelAddress == NULL)
    {
        Print(L"Could not allocate pages for the kernel! Stopping boot!\n");
        Print(L"Failure Reason: ");

        if (Status == EFI_OUT_OF_RESOURCES)
        {
            Print(L"EFI_OUT_OF_RESOURCES\n");
        }
        else if (Status == EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER)
        {
            Print(L"EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER\n");
        }
        else if (Status == EFI_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            Print(L"EFI_NOT_FOUND\n");
        }
        else if (Status != EFI_SUCCESS && kernelAddress == NULL)
        {
            Print(L"UNKNOWN_K_PTR_NULL\n");
        }

        Print(L"Please power off your machine. (I am too lazy to implement ACPI drivers)\n");

        while (true) { }
    }

    uint8_t *kernelBuf = kernelAddress;

    uefi_call_wrapper(kernelHandle->Read, 3, kernelHandle, &kernelSize, kernelBuf);
    

    Print(L"Loaded kernel at address %x\n", kernelBuf);
    


    // ...
    


    terminal_writestring("Loading kernel...\n");

    // Parse the kernel ELF file
    
    uint32_t header_magic = 0;

    header_magic |= (uint32_t)kernelBuf[0] << 24;
    header_magic |= (uint32_t)kernelBuf[1] << 16;
    header_magic |= (uint32_t)kernelBuf[2] << 8;
    header_magic |= (uint32_t)kernelBuf[3];

    // If header_magic == .ELF
    if (header_magic != 0x7F454C46) 
    {
        terminal_writestring("Fatal Error: Kernel is not an ELF file! Stopping boot!\n");
        terminal_writestring("Please power off your machine. (I am too lazy to implement ACPI drivers)\n");

        // Stop here, so the user can power off without causing problems.
        while (true) { }
    }

    // 1 = 32 bit, 2 = 64 bit
    uint8_t header_32_or_64 = kernelBuf[4];

    // The kernel must be 64 bit
    if (header_32_or_64 != 2)
    {
        terminal_writestring("Fatal Error: Kernel is not a 64 bit executable! Stopping boot!\n");
        terminal_writestring("Please power off your machine. (I am too lazy to implement ACPI drivers)\n");

        // Stop here, so the user can power off without causing problems.
        while (true) { }
    }

    // 1 = relocatable, 2 = executable, 3 = shared, 4 = core
    uint16_t header_elf_type = 0;

    header_elf_type |= (uint16_t)kernelBuf[16];
    header_elf_type |= (uint16_t)kernelBuf[17] << 8;

    // The kernel must be executable
    if (header_elf_type != 2)
    {
        terminal_writestring("Fatal Error: Kernel is not executable! Stopping boot!\n");
        terminal_writestring("Please power off your machine. (I am too lazy to implement ACPI drivers)\n");

        // Stop here, so the user can power off without causing problems.
        while (true) { }
    }

    // 0x3E means x86-64
    uint16_t header_instruction_set = 0;

    header_instruction_set |= (uint16_t)kernelBuf[18];
    header_instruction_set |= (uint16_t)kernelBuf[19] << 8;

    // The kernel must be x86-64
    if (header_instruction_set != (uint16_t)0x3E)
    {
        terminal_writestring("Fatal Error: Kernel is not x86-64! Stopping boot!\n");
        terminal_writestring("Please power off your machine. (I am too lazy to implement ACPI drivers)\n");

        // Stop here, so the user can power off without causing problems.
        while (true) { }
    }

    // Quick hack so the kernel can actually execute. I don't know what could go wrong from this,
    // but I know it will mess up something, I just don't know what yet.

    uint64_t prog_entry = 0;

    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[24];
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[25] << 8;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[26] << 16;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[27] << 24;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[28] << 32;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[29] << 40;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[30] << 48;
    prog_entry |= (uint64_t)kernelBuf[31] << 56;

    // Initilize a struct with the required framebuffer info to pass to the kernel, so drawing is still possible

    framebuffer_info_s framebuf;
    framebuf.base_address = gop->Mode->FrameBufferBase;
    framebuf.width = gop->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;
    framebuf.height = gop->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;
    framebuf.pitch = gop->Mode->Info->PixelsPerScanLine;

    terminal_writestring("Jumping to kernel address\n");

    // Jump to the kernel address
    typedef int k_main(framebuffer_info_s framebuffer, EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR* memory_map);
    k_main* k = (k_main*)kernelAddress + prog_entry;
    k(framebuf, memoryMap);
```

Here's the kernel source:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct FramebufferInfo {
    base_address: u64,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    pitch: u32
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct MemoryDescriptor {
    r#type: u32,           // Field size is 32 bits followed by 32 bit pad
    pad: u32,
    physical_start: u64,  // Field size is 64 bits
    virtual_start: u64,   // Field size is 64 bits
    number_of_pages: u64,  // Field size is 64 bits
    attribute: u64       // Field size is 64 bits
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start(framebuffer_info: FramebufferInfo, memory_map: *const MemoryDescriptor) -> ! {
    let framebuffer = framebuffer_info.base_address as *mut u32;
    let pitch = framebuffer_info.pitch;

    // Clear screen
    for y in 0..framebuffer_info.height {
        for x in 0..framebuffer_info.width {
            unsafe {

                *framebuffer.offset((pitch * y + x) as isize) = 0x00000000;
            }
        }
    }

    unsafe {
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 1) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 2) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 3) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 4) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 5) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 6) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 7) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *framebuffer.offset((pitch * 20 + 8) as isize) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }

    loop {}
}

/// This function is called on panic.
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

A bit of useful info, a previous C based kernel had the same issue, but weirdly enough, only when trying to call a function. I have no idea what could cause that, nor why the Rust kernel just fails immediately.

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image]

I tried debugging this in QEMU via GDB, but I couldn't get it to hit a breakpoint even 100 bytes behind of (or at) where the error occurs. And GDB is basically useless for debugging the code itself, as there's no association to the source anywhere, and the kernel is written in Rust which makes this even more difficult to make work.

I think this is a bootloader problem rather than a kernel problem, as
the difference between the kernel location in RAM and the
location the error occurs at is well beyond where the kernel
ends. The 2 things I can think of that could cause this are:

- Somehow the bootloader jumped to an address beyond the kernel entry address, having miscalculated it somehow.
- Somehow the loop at the end of the kernel and the display code don't work,
  which I find unlikely.

I just attempted to load a minimal kernel in ASM, it failed in a slightly different way. Same error, but this time it's within the file.
[image]

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, or a different one, as the error RIP is well within the file and so this could be a problem with how I assembled it.

"kernel" source:

```
.global _start

.text
_start:
    # Loop indefinitely
    loop:
    jmp loop
```

Commands used to compile it:

```
gcc -c src/kernel/core/test.s
ld test.o
```

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't include code, or any debugging like attaching GDB to QEMU as a gdb-remote to find out which instruction caused that #UD fault.  Find the bytes pointed-to by RIP, and see where in your binary that's coming from.  (Or you jumped somewhere outside of your code, then find out how by single-stepping.  Maybe set some breakpoints first to narrow down what region of code to single-step, or have GDB record history so you can rewind from the #UD)

Comment: First, you could at least make the effort to introduce the architectural design choices you make, instead of dumping a repository. That would be a courtesy. You are parsing and loading an ELF in your UEFI bootloader, but it seems to me your parsing is too minimal. You do a few checks on the ELF header and require an ELF executable (i.e not a shared object/PIE) but do you load the segments at the right address? Do you process relocations? Also, you may first want to try a kernel statically linked (no `PT_INTERP` program header entry) that does a simple loop at the entry point.

Comment: @MargaretBloom `Also, you may first want to try a kernel statically linked` I have no clue if that's even possible with the Rust toolchain. I know this bootloader somewhat works as I was able to load a C kernel, but it also had the same problem where it would trigger a "Invalid Opcode" interrupt, but weirdly enough, only when trying to call a function.  Now that I think of it, that would probably be good information to include in the question...

Comment: Presumably the bad instruction is after a jump, so setting breakpoints around there won't work.  GDB can work in assembly mode, `disas` command or `layout asm`, since the problem is at the x86-64 assembly level, not in terms of things in the Rust abstract machine.  (Unless LLVM compiles your Rust code to have a `ud2` instruction somewhere if there's guaranteed undefined behaviour in some path of execution, maybe in an `unsafe{}` block?  It will sometimes do that for C++.)  Disassembling around the fault address will hopefully show you if this is just data that got decoded as code.

Comment: If GDB+QEMU debugging isn't working well, you could also try Bochs with its built-in debugger.  Since it's a simulator, IDK if it could maybe set a breakpoint on a whole region, or maybe show the previous instruction to find out what ran before the instruction that #UD faulted.  Of course the first thing would be to look at the instruction which actually did fault, to see what it is.

Comment: @NickKnack That's exactly why I suggested it :) Don't start with a rust executable, try with a very simple and minimal ELF made in assembly first. If it works, move to more "complex" executables.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I just tried that, same error, although the difference is within the file now, so possibly it's some other problem. I'll add the new information to the question.